# How many passwords can I make with the following requirements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

The password must be exactly 8-characters long. It
must start with a letter, and the rest of the characters can be either letters or numbers 0-9. Capital letters are not included. The password
must contain at least one digit.

Comment: Good point. 0-9 naturally. but essentially 10 digits

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first character is a letter, therefore there are $26$ options. The remaining seven can be either digits or letters, so there are $26 + 10 = 36$ options per slot. We can use the Multiplication Principle here, but because it must contain at least one number, we subtract all passwords that have all letters.

This gives us:

$(26 * 36^7) - (26^8) =  $$1.8286412 * 10^{12}$ passwords.

Comment: Is it a *combination* or a *variation*?

Comment: You're right, I'm not sure about the exact wording. For now I'll edit it to "passwords."

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.